# Crystal Reports: Two tables side by side, from one query BEx

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on CR4E.
My datasource is a query BEx.
The query has the following fields:

- Budget type
- Operation
- Chapter
- Budget (measure)

[image: This is what i need]

I already made a report with this same data but showing first the information of Budget Type 1 and then, below that, the information of budget type 2.

It look like this:
[image: Report already made]

How can I show this two tables side by side?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution because i don't know all the details and requirements, but i believe it points to the right path:

Create two subreports side by side in the same section.

Then you filter the subreport on the left by "budget type 1" (using the subreport link options) and the subreport on the right by "budget type 2".

If you have to align the tops of the operations, you will have to be more creative, specially if the quantities of possible operations and budgets are dynamic. If you need more help, let me know more details.